# What is the JavaScript string newline character?

Tags: javascript, newline

Is `\n` the universal newline character sequence in JavaScript for all platforms? If not, how do I determine the character for the current environment?

I'm not asking about the HTML newline element (`<BR/>`). I'm asking about the newline character sequence used within JavaScript strings.

Comment: I have a multiline input control where the user is expected to enter a newline separated list. I need to parse the list by first splitting the string on newlines.

Comment: @landon9720: For my multiline input controls, I have a `getValue` function that takes the `value` and returns `value.replace(/\r\n/g,'\n')` - just to keep the output consistent across browsers/platforms.

Comment: Good question especially for those who are new to programming! Outside of HTML and in JavaScript it is good to know how to break to the next/new line.

Comment: Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/eol

Comment: I have used this in my console and got 2 different results.
var a = "Hello";
var b = "world";
When I am trying to show this like 
a + "\n" + b;
it gives me the output as 
Hello\nworld
but if I put it in the console like
console.log(a+"\n"+b);
it gives the output as
Hello and world in 2 different lines.

Answer (score 397, accepted):

I've just tested a few browsers using this silly bit of JavaScript:

```js
function log_newline(msg, test_value) {
  if (!test_value) { 
    test_value = document.getElementById('test').value;
  }
  console.log(msg + ': ' + (test_value.match(/\r/) ? 'CR' : '')
              + ' ' + (test_value.match(/\n/) ? 'LF' : ''));
}

log_newline('HTML source');
log_newline('JS string', "foo\nbar");
log_newline('JS template literal', `bar
baz`);
```

```html
<textarea id="test" name="test">

</textarea>
```

IE8 and Opera 9 on Windows use `\r\n`. All the other browsers I tested (Safari 4 and Firefox 3.5 on Windows, and Firefox 3.0 on Linux) use `\n`. They can all handle `\n` just fine when setting the value, though IE and Opera will convert that back to `\r\n` again internally. There's a SitePoint article with some more details called [Line endings in Javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/line-endings-in-javascript/).

Note also that this is independent of the actual line endings in the HTML file itself (both `\n` and `\r\n` give the same results).

When submitting a form, all browsers canonicalize newlines to `%0D%0A` in URL encoding. To see that, load e.g. `data:text/html,<form><textarea name="foo">foo%0abar</textarea><input type="submit"></form>` and press the submit button. (Some browsers block the load of the submitted page, but you can see the URL-encoded form values in the console.)

I don't think you really need to do much of any determining, though. If you just want to split the text on newlines, you could do something like this:

```
lines = foo.value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);
```

Comment: Worked for me, had to use global flag though: /\r\n|\r|\n/g

Comment: @Edson and wrong, since it will treat `\r\n` as two newlines instead of one. If you want short, `/\r?\n/g` will probably do (who still uses Mac OS 9 anyway?).

Comment: Given that the SitePoint article is from 2004, the information there may not be relevant to current JS implementations.

Comment: Match is supposedly much faster than split: http://jsperf.com/regex-split-vs-match

Comment: Does it mean a string can have different lengths in different browsers/systems depending on using `CRLF` vs `CR` for line breaks?

Answer (score 94):

Yes, it is universal.

Although `'\n'` is the universal *newline* characters, you have to keep in mind that, depending on your input, new line characters might be preceded by carriage return characters (`'\r'`).

Comment: \n is the universal *line feed* character (LF). The exact newline byte sequence depends on the platform (\r\n, \n, or \r: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). And *that's* the question landon is asking. You're contradicting yourself when you first say it's the universal newline character, and then say it may be preceded by a CR. Which one is it?

Comment: \n is the newline(line feed) character, even if it is preceded by a carriage return. CR should never be used on its own, although most Windows apis and apps will parse it as a newline. LF works just as well in Windows too. CR is just an artifact from the time when computers were merely electronic typewriters.

Comment: @GolezTrol There are valid reasons to use CR on its own. For instance, returning to the beginning of the line in a console window in order to overwrite the line, without moving to the next line. This is often used to write changing percent progress indicators in command line utilities.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the feedback. Of course, I should never have said "never", because there are indeed applications for a CR on its own. But the question is about Javascript not about command line utilities. Of course there may be a script running in CLI mode (although I don't know if CR will work like you said then), and you may even use Javascript to generate a script which is run in the command line. Those are possible exceptions to the rule, but in the context of the question they seem not to apply. Nevertheless, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: ~preceded~ => **preceded or succeeded**

Answer (score 75):

Don't use "\n". Just try this:

```
var string = "this\
is a multi\
line\
string";
```

Just enter a backslash and keep on trucking! It works like a charm.

Comment: ES6 also supports multiline values with the `tilde` character(otherwise called a backtick).

Comment: @Qasim - FYI, I believe tilde and backtick are different characters, see [`~` Tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) vs [`\`` Backtick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming).

Comment: Ah - Yup, you're right. ES6 uses the backtick character for multiline strings

Comment: Although legal, that is frowned upon in JS circles. It lacks readability. if you can, use ES6's backticks. If not, \n

Comment: Is `"this\"` really less readable than `"this\n"`. Fairly subjective if you ask me... I like saving a character (and keypress) anywhere I can. Developers are lazy :)

Comment: When writing code this works.  It looks like the OP is about parsing text from a textarea though.

Answer (score 62):

It might be easiest to just handle all cases of the new line character instead of checking which case then applying it.  For example, if you need to replace the newline then do the following:

```
htmlstring = stringContainingNewLines.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br>");
```

Comment: Superb.  Works great in later versions FF and IE (not tested older versions though)

Answer (score 28):

Yes, use \n, unless you are generating HTML code, in which case you want to use `<br />`.

Answer (score 17):

With [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), you can use backtick quotes (``` `` ```), which is below the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button on any US layout keyboard with size 75% or greater. So you can write something like this:

```
var text = `fjskdfjslfjsl
skfjslfkjsldfjslfjs
jfsfkjslfsljs`;
```

Comment: perfect suggestion.

Comment: On what keyboard layout? What particular keyboard?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Backtick's ascii code is 96, so You can type it by Alt+96 (on the keypad). It's between Esc and Tab on US keyboard layout. It's on AltGr+7 on Hungarian layout.

Comment: I needed `span.style.whiteSpace = 'pre-wrap'` to make it work. instead of `var text=..` I have `document.getElementById('span1').textContent=...text in backticks`

Comment: When using `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` I can use html formatting and do not need `whiteSpace` together with your solution. So this is the trick.

Answer (score 16):

In an email link function, I use "%0D%0A":

```
function sendMail() {
    var bodydata="Before "+ "%0D%0A";
        bodydata+="After"

    var MailMSG = "mailto:aaa@sss.com"
             + "?cc=07@sss.com"
             + "&subject=subject"
             + "&body=" + bodydata;
    window.location.href = MailMSG;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<a href="#" onClick="sendMail()">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: any one know this type of code for tab key? i am tried "%0D%09" but not working.

Answer (score 8):

Get a line separator for the current browser:

```
function getLineSeparator() {
  var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.value = "\n"; 
  return textarea.value;
}
```

Comment: How about `return textarea.value;`?

Comment: Will using `JSON.stringify` on the result change the character? If I try to view the result in an `alert()` call it doesn't show me the character unless I stringify it first (not that the char needs to be human readable to be effective, of course)

Answer (score 4):

A note - when using ExtendScript JavaScript (the Adobe Scripting language used in applications like Photoshop CS3+), the character to use is "\r". "\n" will be interpreted as a font character, and many fonts will thus have a block character instead.

For example (to select a layer named 'Note' and add line feeds after all periods):

```
var layerText = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName('Note').textItem.contents;
layerText = layerText.replace(/\. /g,".\r");
```

Comment: Was trying to figure out why `\n` and `<br/>` weren't working in my Photoshop script... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
printAccountSummary: function()
    {return "Welcome!" + "\n" + "Your balance is currently $1000 and your interest rate is 1%."}
};
console.log(savingsAccount.printAccountSummary()); // Method
```

Prints:

```
Welcome!
Your balance is currently $1000 and your interest rate is 1%.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem of expressing newline with **\n** or **\r\n**.
Magically the character **\r** which is used for carriage return worked for me like a newline.
So in some cases, it is useful to consider \r too.

Comment: This happens if your string has the ISO-8859-1 charset

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is -- when you are working with JavaScript strings.

If you are generating HTML, though, you will have to use `<br />` tags (not `\n`, as you're not dealing with JavaScript any more).

Answer (score 0):

A practical observation... In my Node.js script I have the following function:

```
function writeToLogFile (message) {
    fs.appendFile('myserverlog.txt', Date() + " " + message + "\r\n", function (err) {
        if (err) 
            throw err;
    });
}
```

First, I had only "\n", but I noticed that when I open the log file in Notepad, it shows all entries on the same line. [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), on the other hand, shows the entries each on their own line. After changing the code to "\r\n", even Notepad shows every entry on its own line.

Comment: On Windows, presumably.

Answer (score -3):

The `\n` is just fine for all cases I've encountered. If you are working with web, use `\n` and don't worry about it (unless you have had any newline-related issues).

Answer (score -15):

You can use `<br/>` and the `document.write/` and `document.writeln` one.

Comment: Please re-read the question. It specifically says he is *not* asking about `<br>`