# Why does Environment.NewLine not work in my String.Replace() but "\n" does?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on displaying some text in a textarea that I've submitted via a form in my ASP.NET MVC app.

I want the line breaks to show when I'm displaying the text back.

Why does

```
Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
```

not work, but

```
Message.Replace("\n", "<br />")
```

does?

Is the breakline character that the browser submits different than the windows Newline "\r\n" ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've answered this yourself...?

Comment: @Marc Gravell, how?  I'm on a windows machine.  You would therefore think a newline would be "\r\n".  This is the value of the Evironment.NewLine.  But, this isn't the value of the newline being submitted by the browser.

Answer (score 7):

If you take a look [at this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character/1156388#1156388), it explains which browsers use '\r\n' and which use '\n' in javascript.  I'm not sure if that would apply to sending information to a server.

Either way, `Environment.NewLine` is the NewLine character for the environment where your web server is running.  Your software running on the web server should not assume that a client's environment is the same as yours, so you should code, assuming that sometimes you will get `Environment.NewLine`, and sometimes you wont.

The common denominator is the `'\n'`, so if you use your second code option, you should handle all of your cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since you must be displaying in an interface which is HTML text, the latter works. For an Outlook html body, `("\n", "<br />")` works but not the former, i.e. Environment.Newline

Btw, thanks for the 2nd one. I was trying to figure out something with html.