# C# how to Regex.Replace "\r\n" (the actual characters, not the line break)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I've got some horrible text that I'm cleaning up using several c# regular expressions. One issue that has me stumped is there are a number of '\r\n' strings in the text, the actual characters not the line breaks.

I've tried:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, "\\r\\n", "");
```

and:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, "\r\n", "");
```

but neither of them work. In the end I had to use:

```
content = content.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
```

to get the project finished, but not being able to do it in a regex annoys me.

Comment: could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981947/how-can-i-remove-r-n-from-a-string-in-c-can-i-use-a-regex

Comment: content.Replace(@"\r\n", "\r\n") is your best choice.

Comment: @Jens: Of course. I meant to say that it's the best choice and far better that using a regex for such a trivial task.

Comment: This question answered here pl check and good solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1982317/2208645

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`\r`, and `\n` have special meaning in Regex, too, so the backslash needs to be escaped. Then, these backslashes needs to be escaped for the c# string, leading to

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, "\\\\r\\\\n", "");
```

or

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\\r\\n", "");
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a good idea to get into the habit of using a verbatim string literals (`@"example"`) when writing regular expressions in C#. In this case you needed this:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"\\r\\n", "\r\n");
```

Otherwise you have to escape each backslash *twice*: once to escape it in the C# string, and then a second time to escape them for the regular expression. So a single backslash would become *four* backslashes with a standard string literal.

Answer (score 3):

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, "\\\\r\\\\n", "");
```

might work. More info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).

Quote:

> In literal C# strings, as well as in
>   C++ and many other .NET languages, the
>   backslash is an escape character. The
>   literal string "\\" is a single
>   backslash. In regular expressions, the
>   backslash is also an escape character.
>   The regular expression \\ matches a
>   single backslash. This regular
>   expression as a C# string, becomes
>   "\\\\". That's right: 4 backslashes
>   to match a single one.

Note: I had to write 8 backslashes in the next to last sentence so 4 backslashes would get displayed ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A better & simple answer is here. It works for me using Regex.

```
public static string GetMultilineBreak(this string content)
{
    return Regex.Replace(content, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Within a specified input string, `Regex.Replace`replaces strings that match a regular expression pattern with a specified replacement string.

A typical usage would be

```
  string input = "This is   text with   far  too     much   " +  "   whitespace.";
  string pattern = "\\s+";
  string replacement = " ";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Doesn't seem like that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Question is old but there has been a change.

```
string temp = Regex.Replace(temp, "\\n", " ");
```

or better enough

```
string temp = Regex.Replace("tab    d_space  newline\n content here   :P", @"\s+", " ");
//tab d_space newline content here :P
```

This works on Universal Windows Applications and probably others too.

Answer (score -3):

Wild guess here:

```
var bslash = System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

content = content.Replace(bslash + "r" + bslash + "n", "");
```