# HTML-Regex Replacement

Tags: html, .net, regex, text

I have string that contains HTML text:

```
string html = "<html>   \r\n\n<body> \n<h1>Hello World</h1>    \r \n \n</body> </html>";
```

I want to clean the text outside the HTML tag. So the string will come out looking like this:

```
string html = "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></html>";
```

I am also using .NET. Is there any built in functionality to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# how to Regex.Replace "\r\n" (the actual characters, not the line break)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311882/c-sharp-how-to-regex-replace-r-n-the-actual-characters-not-the-line-break)

Comment: Agree with @zod, you might not need `RegEx`, but in addition you will like to remove tabs as well `\t`, the same way as it is written for `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: thanks for the link @zod, I am trying

Comment: `/\s/g` will match all whitespace, or you can specify a character class: `/[ \r\n]/g`

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex REGEX_TAGS = new Regex(@">/\r?\n|\r/|\s+<", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string html = "<html>   /r/n/n<body> \n<h1>Hello World</h1>    \r \n \n</body> </html>"
html = REGEX_TAGS.Replace(html, "><");
```

Comment: I got a "feeling" that `Hello World` will become `HelloWorld`... You should not remove spaces or at least change `+` with `{2,}` to catch only pairs of spaces and replace them with single space.

Comment: Your feeling is wrong. The Regex looks for blank spaces and "Hello World" is not blank.

Comment: Agree, but it would have not catch `> Hello world <` in the previous version of your answer.

Comment: everything that is in the >< tags and that's not empty, is user content, maybe the user wants those spaces?

Comment: You know that browsers would not display more than 1 even if they are 20 one after another (` ` is not `&nbsp;`), so why would we keep them? Do not get me wrong, I am trying to improve your answer against the question.