# How do I remove \r\n from string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to figure out an easy way remove \r\n from a string.

Example:
    text = "this.is.a.string.\r\nthis.is.a.string\r\n"

I tried:

`text.Replace("\r\n", "")` and `text.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty)`, but it doesn't work. `\r\n` is still in the string...

The result should be: "this.is.a.string.this.is.a.string"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove "\r\n" from a string in c#? Can I use a regEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981947/how-can-i-remove-r-n-from-a-string-in-c-can-i-use-a-regex)

Comment: Use `string.replace()`

Comment: do you assign result of `text.Replace()` call somewhere? It does not replace it in-place

Comment: you must realize that strings are immutable,every "string method" you use returns to you a NEW string so you must assign to a string variable that be your text variable or a new one.

Comment: Better solution has given here pl check
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1982317/2208645

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This reads better:

```
text = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings in .NET are immutable and so you cannot change an existing string - you can only create a new one. The `Replace` method returns the modified result, i.e.

```
text = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
text = JObject.Parse(text);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I had used this code in a web API where \r\n was not working.

input:

 {\r\n  \"LOINC\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"LOINC_NUM\": \"10362-2\",\r\n      \"COMPONENT\": \"Endomysium Ab.IgA\",\r\n      \"PROPERTY\": \"PrThr\",\r\n      \"TIME_ASPCT\": \"Pt\",\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n};

output: 

{
  "LOINC": [
    {
      "LOINC_NUM": "10362-2",
      "COMPONENT": "Endomysium Ab.IgA",
      "PROPERTY": "PrThr",
      "TIME_ASPCT": "Pt"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: The best answer so far

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the return value back to the variable?

```
text = text.Replace(@"\r\n", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

It returns a value. You need to say `text = ...`

```
text = text.Replace(@"\r\n", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
text = text .Replace("\\r\\n", "");
```

It's work for me ;)

Answer (score -1):

You better try this.

```
text = text.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Hope this work.