# Regex find expression within text

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to avoid the basic replace, the loops and the "if" everywhere.

I am looking for an expression in a full text that could get me this result:

```
\n\n\Lorem\n\n\t\n\r\n\Ipsum \t\t\t Lorem\t\t\tHello Stackoverflow!
Lorem\r\t\nTest lorem ipsum V++ \n\rO+\n V2.0
```

The result I am expecting is all the words except the `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, I need the `Lorem`, `Ipsum`, `Test` and `Hello Stackoverflow` on the first sentence and also the `V++` and the `O+`. but not the `V2.0`

Is there any better way than removing the bad chars and extract the words via a regex?

Comment: Why don't you need `Lorem` and `Ipsum`? Also, if you're "quite bad at regex", why do you find it easier than an `If`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove "\r\n" from a string in c#? Can I use a regEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981947/how-can-i-remove-r-n-from-a-string-in-c-can-i-use-a-regex)

Comment: Have you googled it first? there are plenty of SO questions about that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I actually need the Lorem and Ipsum actually. I also didn't say that I could have in the text some text like 'V2.0' which I do not want either.

Comment: @d.popov: I have been browsing the web for the past 3 hours so actually I did.

Comment: This question can't really be answered. There is no logic behind what you want to have and what not. Why don't you want `V2.0`? What about `V3.0`? Do you want that?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Actually I don't want it either because of some special characters (.,\/?:;'[]{}!@#$%^&*()) this is more or less the list I can't have.

Comment: But `V`, `2` and `0` are not in that list. So, maybe you want to exclude *words* that contain one of these characters with a word being anything that is delimited by whitespace?

Comment: Yeah this is what I actually need.

Comment: What about the single backslashes in front of the first Lorem and the first Ipsum? Are they an error in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to achieve [what you really want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798844/regex-find-expression-within-text#comment49647737_30798844) using regex.

I would go with ordinary C# code:

```
var input = @"\n\n\Lorem\n\n\t\n\r\n\Ipsum \t\t\t Lorem\t\t\tHello Stackoverflow!
Lorem\r\t\nTest lorem ipsum V++ \n\rO+\n V2.0";
var separators = new [] {"\r", "\n", "\t", "\\n", "\\t", "\\r", "\\" };
var invalidCharacters = @".,\/?:;'[]{}!@#$%^&*()".ToCharArray();
var rawWords = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
var words = rawWords.Where(x => !invalidCharacters.Any(y => x.Contains(y)));
```

Please note, that this removes the `Hello Stackoverflow!` because it contains one of the invalid characters: `!`

This is the content of `rawWords`:

- Lorem
- Ipsum
- Lorem
- Hello Stackoverflow!
- Lorem
- Test lorem ipsum V++
- O+
- V2.0

And this is the content of `words`:

- Lorem
- Ipsum
- Lorem
- Lorem
- Test lorem ipsum V++
- O+

As your requirements are still unclear - and frankly, I think that your example text contains errors - this is the best I can do. From here on, you should use this code and modify it the way you need it to get you what you actually need.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did manage to do it more or less the same way. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`\s` is a matcher for a whitespace character in a Regular Expression.

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html:

> `\s` stands for "whitespace character". Again, which characters this
>   actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors
>   discussed in this tutorial, it includes `[ \t\r\n\f]`. That is: `\s`
>   matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed.

So you could just write a Regex for `\s` and replace all matches with `string.empty`.