# remove \r\n with newline in json string

Tags: c#, json, notepad++

I created a JSON string in C# using this code.

```
string jsonFormatted = JValue.Parse(JSONresult).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

when I paste the json Formatted string in notepad++, I get lot of \r\n and "\". I want to replace all \r\n  with newline. when I tried to replace \r\n with empty space, all \r\n goes away and I can format the string using JSON Viewer -Format JSON plugin, but all \r\n are replaced by LF. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

I want the \r\n to be replaced by new line CRLF. My JSON file is huge so it is difficult to change all \r\n by hand.

[image]

Below is the sample of my partial JSON string:

```
"{\r\n  \"header\": {\r\n    \"tenantId\": \"23213\",\r\n    \"requestType\": \"PreciseIdOnly\",\r\n    \"clientReferenceId\": \"3243214\",\r\n    \"expRequestId\": \"\",\r\n    \"txnId\": \"\",\r\n    \"messageTime\": \"2020-06-05T19:35:45Z\",\r\n
```

Can I do this in either C# or notepad++ or any other editor.

replacing \r\n with empty space or string.empty is not working because the newline character does not come up in notepad++ if I replace the string with \r\n. I want a new line too along with \r\n gone.

Below is my entire JSON file

```
{
    "header": {
        "tenantId": "23213",
        "requestType": "PreciseIdOnly",
        "clientReferenceId": "3243214",
        "expRequestId": "",
        "txnId": "",
        "messageTime": "2020-06-05T19:35:45Z",
        "options": {}
    },
    "payload": {
        "control": [
            {
                "option": "SUBSCRIBER_PREAMBLE",
                "value": "23213"
            },
            {
                "option": "SUBSCRIBER_OPERATOR_INITIAL",
                "value": "qq"
            },
            {
                "option": "SUBSCRIBER_SUB_CODE",
                "value": "1231"
            },
            {
                "option": "PID_USERNAME",
                "value": "abc"
            },
            {
                "option": "PID_PASSWORD",
                "value": "aaa"
            },
            {
                "option": "PRODUCT_OPTION",
                "value": "24"
            }
        ],
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": "APPLICANT_CONTACT_ID_1",
                "person": {
                    "typeOfPerson": "",
                    "personIdentifier": "",
                    "personDetails": {
                        "dateOfBirth": "2020-06-05",
                        "yearOfBirth": "",
                        "age": "",
                        "gender": "",
                        "noOfDependents": "",
                        "occupancyStatus": "",
                        "mothersMaidenName": "",
                        "spouseName": ""
                    },
                    "names": [
                        {
                            "id": "",
                            "firstName": "test1",
                            "middleNames": "test2",
                            "surName": "test3",
                            "nameSuffix": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "addresses": [
                    {
                        "id": "Main_Contact_Address_0",
                        "addressType": "CURRENT",
                        "poBoxNumber": "",
                        "street": "42123 test drive",
                        "street2": "",
                        "postTown": "a",
                        "postal": "33232",
                        "stateProvinceCode": "qa"
                    }
                ],
                "telephones": [
                    {
                        "id": "Main_Phone_0",
                        "number": ""
                    }
                ],
                "emails": [
                    {
                        "id": "MAIN_EMAIL_0",
                        "type": "",
                        "email": ""
                    }
                ],
                "identityDocuments": [
                    {
                        "documentNumber": "12321343",
                        "hashedDocumentNumber": "",
                        "documentType": "SSN"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "application": {
            "productDetails": "",
            "applicants": [
                {
                    "contactId": "APPLICANT_CONTACT_ID_1",
                    "applicantType": "APPLICANT"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove "\r\n" from a string in C#? Can I use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981947/how-can-i-remove-r-n-from-a-string-in-c-can-i-use-a-regular-expression)

Comment: No, I tried to replace \r\n with string.empty. When I do that, the new line character is gone. I want newline too.

Comment: `\r\n` **is** a newline. Why do you want to remove it? Your question seems to be "how do I replace a newline with a newline?" which is, shall we say, an odd question to ask.

Comment: If I well understand, you want to replace `\r\n` with `\n`, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened to me too. What you can do is replace all \r\n with space in notepad++ something like this:

[image]

and then replace all \n with \r\n. Make sure Extended \n\r\t i selected in replace window and you will get all CRLF in your notepad. Let me know if you see any issues

Answer (score 1):

Try Disabling the 'Show All Characters' option in notepad++ to see how your json is getting formatted.

[image]

Comment: JSON format is totally good. I even verified the JSON validity with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  , I do want the newline character in JSON so that I can test the JSON in SOAPUI

Comment: can you share the masked json file here i can take a look @Anjali

Comment: I put my entire JSON file in my post

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can replace `\r\n` with `\n` in C#

```
string responseString = "your json data which includes \r\n";

// replace \r\n with \n
string data = responseString.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
// replace \" with "
string refinedString = data.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: What is the point of using regex here?

Comment: To remove \r\n from the json. And refine it with replacing \" with "

Comment: Ok, I'll be more concrete. What us the point of using regex over `String.Replace` here?

Comment: Because it is not possible to use regex inside `string.replace`. Meaning that we would have to write one by one `string.Replace("\r", ""); string.Replace("\n", "");` . To avoid this, I used regex instead.

Comment: _"I want to replace all \r\n with newline."_ - from OP.

Comment: Thank you for that! Let me adjust my answer accordingly