# JavaScript Newline Character

Tags: javascript

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character), this ...

```
lines = foo.value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
```

is one way to split a string, but how do I join it back with newlines?

Also, I wonder if I is say linux which uses whichever newline character, then switch to windows, won't my web app break? The newlines become not recognized? Or maybe the browser does some conversion?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Split it on /\r?\n/, in case the string includes the carriage returns with newlines.

join it with '\n', in any browser and any os.

Comment: In the node REPL you'll see a literal `\n` in the output for `['foo','bar'].join('\n')`, however if you run `console.log(['foo','bar'].join('\n'))` you'll see the expected result. Hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 64):

If you want to join using newline characters, just do:

```
lines.join("\r\n");
```

But if you want to display on the HTML page, you'd want to wrap each line in `<p></p>` tags:

```
html = "<p>" + lines.join("</p><p>") + "</p>";
```

Comment: In HTML, you can also use lines.join("\r\n") and it works so long as you use the <pre> tag.

Comment: @MatthewRideout Or any element with `white-space: pre;`.

Answer (score 47):

You can use the `Array` object's [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to glue together array elements into a string:

```js
lines.join("\r\n");
```

In CSS: remember to use

```css
white-space: pre;
```

Comment: Is that only for Windows? In Linux the new line is `\n` isn't it? I guess the code will work anyways?

Comment: @JacobRelkin: didn't work for me using the .split('\r\n') but does work with .split(/\r?\n/)

Answer (score 2):

The following seems a future-proof, os-independent code:

```js
lines.join(`
`)
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, join is the best, but here is the hard way (untested, I hope it's not too trivial):

```
var result;

for (i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
   result+=lines[i]+"\r\n"; //depends on OS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used '\r' is OK, macOS 12.6, chrome 109.0.5414.119

```
lines.join('\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

lines.join('\n') worked for me to get elements in new line in windows machine.