# Use Angular Value Input: Split Array List into Separate Items using New Line Character

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a list of items.
I am trying to split them with a delimiter.
It is working with semicolons, but not working with newline characters. How can I fix this, to work with new line?
 Would like to show line breaks.

**This works:**

```
[value]="productList.join('; ')"
```

**Does not work for**

```
[value]="productList.join('\n ')"
[value]="productList.join('\r ')"
[value]="productList.join('\n\r ')"
```

Currently using Angular 8 with Typescript.

Resource: [JavaScript Newline Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321041/javascript-newline-character)

Comment: Define "doesn't work". If you want to show linebreaks in HTML you need to use `<br />` tags. Consecutive whitespace is ignored; that's just how HTML and browsers work.

Comment: you have to replace `\n` for `<br />` if you are using a textarea as an input and an HTML element as an output. This is not something related to angular is just how the web works.

Comment: It can; it's generally the wrong approach. If it works for your usecase, great.

Comment: @AlanSmith5482 Because that will preserve *all* whitespace, which *may* be acceptable in some situations, but it's almost always better to use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working, create a css class with white-space

**HTML:**

```
[value]="productList.join('\n ')"
```

**CSS:**

```
.test{
  white-space: pre !important;
}
```