# How do I create a new line in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, newline, line-breaks

```
var i;
for(i=10; i>=0; i= i-1){
   var s;
   for(s=0; s<i; s = s+1){
    document.write("*");
   }
   //i want this to print a new line
   /document.write(?);

}
```

I am printing a pyramid of stars, I can't get the new line to print.

Comment: document.write("<br>"); // if using a .html

Comment: Related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1155678/465053).

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Use the `\n` for a newline character.

```
document.write("\n");
```

You can also have more than one:

```
document.write("\n\n\n"); // 3 new lines!  My oh my!
```

However, if this is rendering to HTML, you will want to use the HTML tag for a newline:

```
document.write("<br>");
```

The string `Hello\n\nTest` in your source will look like this:

```
Hello!

Test
```

The string `Hello<br><br>Test` will look like this in HTML source:

```
Hello<br><br>Test
```

The HTML one will render as line breaks for the person viewing the page, the `\n` just drops the text to the next line in the source (if it's on an HTML page).

Comment: By definition, if the OP is using `document.write`, it's an HTML page, not an XHTML page. `<br>` is the correct linebreak for an HTML page. `<br />` is XHTML.

Comment: thanks for the ``` document.write("<br>");``` detail. i was about to get crazy

Answer (score 36):

how about:

```
document.write ("<br>");
```

(assuming you are in an html page, since a line feed alone will only show as a space)

Answer (score 14):

Use a `<br>` tag to create a line break in the document

```
document.write("<br>");
```

Here's a sample fiddle

- http://jsfiddle.net/g6eAF/

Comment: +1 as this seems to be what the OP is *really* looking for :) (br vs \n)

Comment: How do you know? Good to point out BR, but a PRE could have just as easily been in there too. If they are building ASCII art, my thought is it's plaintext.

Comment: @Jared: How do you call `document.write` in a plain text document? (E.g., how do you put in the `script` tag?) Good point about the `pre`, though, could easily be a `pre` section.

Comment: @T.J. - The display is plaintext, as in ASCII art. It's still an HTML document, although, it's just showing it as plaintext display.

Comment: @Jared: Yeah, I took your point. (I thought your other bit was about a `text/plain` doc, but I think I was clear about the `pre` being a good point.)

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, write to an element with the CSS `white-space: pre` and use `\n` for newline character.

Comment: Thanks! That was close, and `white-space: pre-wrap` did exactly what I wanted!
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. My app has a div, that for some reason, was taking the \n as a whitespace and NOT as a new line.

Answer (score 4):

Use `"\n"`:

```
document.write("\n");
```

<strike>Note, it has to be surrounded in double quotes for it to be interpreted as a newline.</strike> No it doesn't.

Comment: Outputting a newline in an HTML page won't introduce a new line in an HTML document. (And it doesn't have to be double quotes, single quotes are fine as well.)

Comment: @T.J. - Unless there's a PRE involved?

Comment: Ooh, except for your point commenting on another answer about a `pre` element. Good point. If outputting ASCII art to a `pre` section, `\n` may well be the right thing... (Edit: LOL, overlapping comments.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Here's an example of what I meant (crudely developed): http://jsfiddle.net/wT3Ab/

Comment: @Jared: Oh, your comment about `pre` was perfectly clear. (Closed the tag for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wT3Ab/1/) Best,

Comment: @T.J. - I know, I just wanted to put a demo so it was clearly defined. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`document.writeln()` is what you are looking for or `document.write('\n' + 'words')` if you are looking for more granularity in when the new line is used

Answer (score 4):

In html page:

```
document.write("<br>");
```

but if you are in JavaScript file, then this will work as new line:

```
document.write("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

For a string I just write `"\n"` to give me a new line. For example, typing `console.log("First Name: Rex" + "\n" + "Last Name: Blythe");` Will type:

First Name: Rex

Last Name: Blythe

Answer (score 1):

To create a new line, symbol is '\n'

```
var i;
for(i=10; i>=0; i= i-1){
   var s;
   for(s=0; s<i; s = s+1){
    document.write("*");
   }
   //i want this to print a new line
   document.write('\n');

}
```

If you are outputting to the page, you'll want to use `"<br/>"` instead of `'/n'`;

[Escape characters in JavaScript](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm)

Comment: It doesn't have to be in double quotes?

Comment: No double and singe quotes are the same in JavaScript.  You just can't start with a double quote and end with a single one.

Comment: Well, I know that. Just didn't know single and doubles were treated the same in JS. Must be stuck in PHP.

Comment: Moving between language is always a pain :)

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Learn something new every day. :) Harmless error, probably.

Comment: It's good practice to use one or the either, but not both, especially in the same function. (The more you know ......*)

Answer (score 1):

\n dosen't work. Use html tags

```
document.write("<br>");
document.write("?");
```

Answer (score 1):

\n --> newline character is not working for inserting a new line.

```
    str="Hello!!";
    document.write(str);
    document.write("\n");
    document.write(str);
```

But if we use below code then it works fine and it gives new line.

```
    document.write(str);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(str);
```

> **Note::** I tried in **Visual Studio Code**.

Comment: This assumes that the text will be displayed as HTML. Not sufe if that is really a generic answer here.

Answer (score 1):

you can also pyramid of stars like this

```
for (var i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
     var py = "";
     for (var j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
         py += j;

     }
     console.log(py);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("\n");
```

won't work if you're executing it (`document.write();`) multiple times.

I'll suggest you should go for:

```
document.write("<br>");
```

**P.S** I know people have stated this answer above but didn't find the *difference* anywhere so :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your code between the HTML pre tag.

Comment: kindly add code too. it would be better to understand

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy actually. :D

To make a new line, you only need to use `\n` "function".
For HTML related-projects, use only `<br>`, like in actual HTML script. :)

```
var i;
for(i=10; i>=0; i= i-1){
   var s;
   for(s=0; s<i; s = s+1){
    document.write("*");
   }
   // Here's the change
   document.write('\n');

}
```

**THE OUTPUT**

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

**BUT**, be careful the output above won't work in some HTML related projects. For that, you need to use `<br>` - like in HTML :D

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a JavaScript file (.js) then use `document.write("\n");`.  If you are in a html file (.html or . htm) then use `document.write("<br/>");`.

Answer (score -1):

your solution is

```
var i;
for(i=10; i>=0; i= i-1){
   var s;
   for(s=0; s<i; s = s+1){
    document.write("*");
   }
   //printing new line
   document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use below link: [New line in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G446XR3VT0NX)

```
  var i;
for(i=10; i>=0; i= i-1){
   var s;
   for(s=0; s<i; s = s+1){
    document.write("*");
   }
   //i want this to print a new line
   /document.write('<br>');

}
```

Comment: Your link is broken, and your code example says nothing that the accepted answer from 2011 doesn't already say.

Comment: Well, the link is fixed, but it points to an explanation-free demo and you still aren't saying anything now already said in 2011.