# Use line break in document.write() output

Tags: javascript

How can I use break line in my output? There is something wrong in `document.write`.

Please review my code and give me best solution..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function FahToCent (degFah)
    {
        var degCent = new Array ();

        for (var loopCounter = 0;  loopCounter <=2; loopCounter++)
        {
            degCent[loopCounter] = 5/9 * (degFah[loopCounter] - 32);
        }

        return degCent;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var degFah = new Array ();

    for (var loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <= 2; loopCounter++)
    {
        degFah[loopCounter] = prompt ("Enter Temperature in Fahrenheit");
    }

    document.write (FahToCent (degFah)+"<br>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does anyone still use `document.write`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a new line in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript)

Comment: *Does anyone still use document.write?* ~ * ~ Yes, excellent in stack snippets!

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
 function FahToCent (degFah)
{
    return 5/9 * (degFah - 32);;
}

var degFah = new Array ();
for (var loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <= 2; loopCounter++)
{
    degFah[loopCounter] = prompt ("Enter Temperature in Fahrenheit");
    document.write(FahToCent (degFah[loopCounter])+"<br>");   
}
```

Example Link : http://jsfiddle.net/pradkumar_n/Bucjz/

Comment: Or there could be another approach where we can loop through the array please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

just add break tag in your function FahtoCent

```
 degCent[loopCounter] = 5/9 * (degFah[loopCounter] - 32)+"<BR>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `degCent` as an Array, which is passed to `document.write()` as an argument. This argument is supposed to be a string, and now it's an array. Hence it's automatically converted to a string before outputting, using `Array.toString()` method. This method returns a comma-separated list of array values (as a string).

However, you can convert the returned array to a string, and add linebreaks with the same manouver, using an Array-method called [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Methods). Like this:

```
document.write(FahToCent(degFah).join('<br/>'));
```

However, `document.write()` is considered as a bad practise for DOM manipulations. Please check some advanced methods to show the output in the document:

[MDN: `innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML), [MDN: `appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not altogether certain of what you are asking here but I think you just want to go to a new line after the code runs.  In which case you need writeline rather than write and remove "br" tag

```
document.writeline (FahToCent (degFah));
```

Comment: Caution to anyone reading this answer. The `document.writeline` method does not exist. I'll give the original poster the benefit of the doubt and assume they meant `document.writeln`. But they really should've made sure the method actually exists and was spelled correctly before using it in an answer.