# Add a new line after text has been added to a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am populating a textbox using the code below. I would like to make the textbox multiline and every time the code is executed it appends the new text to a new line.

Is there a way to do this using the code below?

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getSelected(source, eventArgs) {
        var s = $get("<%=NameTextBox.ClientID %>").value;
        document.getElementById('<%= NPTextBox.ClientID %>').value = s.substring(s.length - 10);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `.value = s.substring(s.length - 10) & vbcrlf);`

Comment: It says vbcrlf is undefined?

Comment: Sorry I assumed since it was vb code it would work, my last attempt is for you to try `\n'` like in this post , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript.... hope this helps. So Possibly after your `document.GetElement` ... do `document.write("\n");`

Comment: I tried that and its throwing errors I added the document.write("\n"); after my last line

Comment: have you tried write('\n'); single quote? also what errors

Comment: Tried that as well, I get the error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the newline character (`'\n'`), like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getSelected(source, eventArgs) {
        var s = $get("<%=NameTextBox.ClientID %>").value;
        document.getElementById('<%= NPTextBox.ClientID %>').value += s.substring(s.length - 10) + '\n';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just like he's saying here , @user1342164

Comment: Thanks when I try the it just replaces the previous text so another words the second result replaces the first? instead of just having 2 items listed

Comment: You need to append the result of `s.substring(s.length - 10) + '\n';`, see updated answer.