# why back slash to write in multiple lines not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am practicing javascript using google chrome developer console. As per my knowledge we use \ to write in multiple lines on document with Javascript. I try to write

```
document.write("Hello world \ How are you?");
```

But it simply displays "Hello world How are you". I was expecting Hello world and How are you in different lines.

Comment: A backslash is used to put an escape code in a string.  You should search for "javascript string escape codes" or something similar

Comment: \ allows *code* on different lines, but isn't a physical new line...

Answer (score 0):

the browser uses HTML to display stuff. 
In HTML you make a new line using `<br/>` (or `<br>` or `</br>`) for "break row".
 If you want to break it into two lines, use this tag instead of `\n`.
Greets!

Comment: @GaneshDev So here is the thing: If you write `\n` in js, it would result in a linebreak in that string indeed. So if you want to print it out to the console, you can write `console.log("Hello \nWorld")` and it indeed would result in two separate lines. If you use document.write("Hello \nWorld") it indeed would result in a linebreak inside the source-code (!). You can check that by pressing Ctrl+U and looking it up in the source code. However, the browser will ingnore this, as he only interprets markup-tags. So you need to use `<br>` if you want a linebreak on your webpage. Greets!

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was searching for pure javascript for multiple lines without using html.

Comment: @GaneshDev So hope you got your answer now? Or still any questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can write New Line in JavaScript  by `<br>` if you will Run it in chrome Console ,

```
document.write("Hello world <br> How are you?");
```

but [check it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758185/4967569) to know more for New-Line in JavaScript