# New line in JavaScript in the front of the string?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble creating a new line in JavaScript. When I use document.write() and enter \n at the start, it doesn't create a new line.
How do I create new lines?
(By the way, I am just a beginner)

Code:

```
var myString;    
myString = 42;    
document.write("myString is currently: " + myString);    
myString = myString + 1;    
document.write("\n myString is currently: " + myString);
```

Comment: You're writing HTML, which means you need `<br>`. If you want `\n` to create a new line, you need to wrap the text in `<pre>` and `</pre>`

Comment: It's better to learn not to use `document.write` even in exercises; it should be used only in very few special cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a new line in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `document.write` that will render the text inside it as an `HTML` thus, the `\n` is not detected as a new line character but simply as a escape character. That is why you will get the output without `n` as `n` is escaped by backslash `\`. So, in your case you need to use the HTML line break `<br/>`.

```
var myString;    
myString = 42;    
document.write("myString is currently: " + myString);    
myString = myString + 1;    
document.write("<br/> myString is currently: " + myString);
```

Comment: Explanation will be helpful for the OP to understand

Comment: Not my downvote, but `\n` signifies a newline character. It doesn't display "n" on the page.

Comment: Open your browser console and paste this document.write("a\n myString is currently: ");  and hit enter

Comment: I did, and it printed "a myString is currently:" as was expected.

Comment: That is what i have written in answer

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked, and I also didn't see the "n" but at least this works!

Comment: "the \n is not detected as a new line character" is not true, it *is* a newline character but the browser's display model ignores newlines by default. You can see the newline if you inspect the text in the console. (I did misread the next sentence, sorry.)