# How do I start a new line in Javascript without using document.write()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```js
var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
console.log(window);
console.log(window.location);
infoDiv.textContent += "The URL of this page is " + window.location.href;
// i am hoping the following sentence can start in a new line
infoDiv.textContent += "The user agent is " + window.navigator.userAgent;
```

I tried `document.write("\n")` as people suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript), but Chrome gives me this violation warning:

> [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: infoDiv.textContent += "\nThe user agent is " + window.navigator.userAgent;

Comment: Thanks! I tried that as well, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks in HTML are created with the `<br>` element (generally *between* text nodes). Paragraphs with the `<p>` element (generally *around* text nodes).

In either case you'll need to stop twiddling `textContent` because it will wipe out any elements you create.

Use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode), and [`infoDiv.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Answer (score 0):

You can append elements instead of text:

```
var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");
infoDiv.append("The URL of this page is " + window.location.href);
// append new line
infoDiv.append(document.createElement('br'));
infoDiv.append("The user agent is " + window.navigator.userAgent);
```