# creating newline in javascript using "\n" character

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a very basic code in javascript and I'm looking forward to use `"\n"` for newline but it seems to not be working.

I have seen alternate solutions in other posts, but I wonder why is `"\n"` not working here.

Here's my code.

```html
<html>

<body>
    <h2>welcome to java script</h2>
    <script>
        var x = 10;
        var y = 20;
        var sum = x + y;
        var mult = x * y;
        document.write("the sum is " + sum);
        document.write("\n");
        document.write(" the product is " + mult);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript

Please use <br/>

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen using <br/> as one of the solutions in other posts but my question is why is "\n" not working in my case?

Comment: with DOM (html) \n won't work as it will be considered normal string.

Answer (score 1):

The newline character (`\n`) breaks line within a string not in the document.

To break the line in the document you have to use the HTML `<br/>` element.

```html
<html>

<body>
    <h2>welcome to java script</h2>
    <script>
        var x = 10;
        var y = 20;
        var sum = x + y;
        var mult = x * y;
        document.write("the sum is " + sum);
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write(" the product is " + mult);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"\n" works in text files.You are writing to the DOM in HTML; the DOM recognizes

```html
<br />
```

Use that instead.

Comment: then why does "\n" work in java code

Comment: The question is: when it works in Java, where is that code running? Is it running in the browser? It is about where the code is run and how it is interpreted.