# Making a new line in js string

Tags: javascript

I want to make a new line between Editing and Become.
I tried \n but it didn't work
Any clue?

```
var i = 0;
var text = "Animation - Web Development- Video Editing Become a member & More.";

function typeWriter(){
    if(i < text.length){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
    }
}
typeWriter();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a new line in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, `\n` is one possible way, but I can't see any `\n` in your code. Also, remember that HTML doesn't render line feeds, in case that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a line break to your string with `\n`. In your code check to see if a line break is the character, if it is, replace it with `<br/>`

```js
var i = 0;
var text = "Animation - Web Development- Video Editing\nBecome a member & More.";

function typeWriter() {
  var ch = text.charAt(i)
  if (ch === '\n') {
    ch = '<br/>'
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += ch
  i++;
  i < text.length && setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
}
typeWriter();
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because HTML doesn't render line feeds, you need to add a condition in your function or adapt your HTML code.

#### Solution #1

Update your Javascript function, add a special case in your first `if` statement:

```js
var i = 0;
var text = "Animation - Web Development- Video Editing Become a member & More.";

function typeWriter(){
  if(i < text.length){
    if(text.charAt(i) === "\n") 
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += "<br/>";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
  }
}
typeWriter();
```

In that case, HTML will render `<br/>` tag by adding a new line. Don't forget to add the `\n` in your `text` variable.

#### Solution #2:

Use `<pre>` HTML tag, not recommended but content will be rendered too, without changing your Javascript function.

```
<pre id="text"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `/n` isn't a good practice here, if you're receiving those data from a 3rd-party API for example, you won't be able to get `/n` in the text. So, your best bet is checking for the exact word you're looking for, and add break line after it.

### Solution Explanation

The `wordCheck` boolean value is set to `true` by default, so our condition below keep running, until we found the word `Editing` in the printed text. In that case, we add a line break, set `false` value to `wordCheck` to prevent adding line breaks later.

*I cached the element `txtElement` for better code readability.*

```js
var i = 0;
var text = "Animation - Web Development- Video Editing Become a member & More.";
var wordCheck = true;

function typeWriter(){
  var txtElement = document.getElementById("text");
  
  if(i < text.length){
    txtElement.innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);

    // Here's we detect if the value reached the word "Editing", if so, we do break line
    var currentVal = txtElement.innerHTML;
    if(wordCheck && currentVal.indexOf('Editing') >= 1) {
      txtElement.innerHTML += "<br>";
      wordCheck = false;
    }
  }
}
typeWriter();
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```