# print in new line in callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code for callback function in javascript:

```
callback(
        undefined,

        body.current.weather_descriptions[0] +
          "." +
          "It is currently " +
          body.current.temperature +
          " degrees. It feels like " +
          body.current.feelslike +
          " degrees. There is " +
          body.current.precip +
          "% chance of rain."
      );
```

My desired output is:

```
Varanasi, Uttar Pradesh, India

Partly cloudy.
It is currently 26 degrees. 
It feels like 26 degrees.
There is 0% chance of rain.
```

But my output coming is:

```
Varanasi, Uttar Pradesh, India

Partly cloudy.It is currently 26 degrees. It feels like 26 degrees. There is 0% chance of rain.
```

I tried many things but not getting desired output, can you help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a new line in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Ok to literally throw back at you the solved version of what you gave us..

```
callback(
    undefined,

    body.current.weather_descriptions[0] +
      ".\n" +
      "It is currently " +
      body.current.temperature +
      " degrees.\nIt feels like " +
      body.current.feelslike +
      " degrees.\nThere is " +
      body.current.precip +
      "% chance of rain."
  );
```

Comment: No changes are observed actually after doing this.

Comment: what? ok please share the source code of this `callback` then @GauravSingh

Answer (score 0):

On mobile, so excuse the lack of formatting.

Add in “\n\r” each place you want to add a new line. So something like

“It is currently: “ + your.call.data + “\n\rdegrees outside”.

Comment: I tried this @MCA but it is getting printed as it it, like /n/rdegrees outside.

Comment: Wrong way! you actually need them to be backslashes, not forward slashes. "\n\r". LMK if that works!

Comment: I did that too.

Comment: Why not try first converting your output to a string if it is not working? `var output = "";` and then `output +=` all of your above callback function, including `"\n\r"`

Comment: https://github.com/gauravmnnit/weather-website

This is the github link for that, src/utils/forecast

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display this in a browser, use `"<br>"` tag to places where you need the new lines:

```
callback(
        undefined,

        body.current.weather_descriptions[0] +"<br>"
          "." +
          "It is currently " +
          body.current.temperature +
          " degrees." +"<br>" "It feels like " +
          body.current.feelslike 
          " degrees." +"<br>"+ "There is " +
          body.current.precip +
          "% chance of rain."
      );
```

If you need to display this in a console, use `"\n"` to places where you need the new lines:

```
callback(
        undefined,

        body.current.weather_descriptions[0] +"\n"
          "." +
          "It is currently " +
          body.current.temperature +
          " degrees." +"\n" "It feels like " +
          body.current.feelslike 
          " degrees." +"\n"+ "There is " +
          body.current.precip +
          "% chance of rain."
      );
```

Comment: This answer would only apply if the string is being rendered by a browser as HTML. For any other environment (ie. a CLI application) it will just print literal "<br>" characters.

Comment: I would recommend using template strings

Comment: I tried doing these things @HarshanaSerasinghe but it's not working, after adding "<br>" instead of breaking line it is getting printed as <br> at that place.

Comment: Where do you use this?

Comment: https://github.com/gauravmnnit/weather-website

it is the github link for that project, src/utils/forecast

Answer (score 0):

You can insert literal newline character in a string with `\n`. For example:

```js
const myString = "Hello,\nThat's a nice Tnettenba.";
console.log(myString);
```

```
Hello,
That's a nice Tnettenba.
```

Or, you can use backticks to create a string literal with newlines. For example:

```
const anotherString = `Hello,
That's a nice Tnettenba.`;
```

Will produce the same output as above.

Using strings delineated with backticks is helpful in this situation, as any whitespace (newlines, indents) are preserved, which is often desirable when formatting text for display. Eg.

```js
const myTable = `
  | ID  | Name            |
  -------------------------
  | 001 | Hello, World!   |
  | 002 | Brave New World |
`;
```

Will output:

```
  | ID  | Name            |
  -------------------------
  | 001 | Hello, World!   |
  | 002 | Brave New World |
```

Note the leading spaces.

Comment: It is inside the callback function and these values are returned by the function, so can't do this but I tried this too and it's not working.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry. Could you share what you have attempted? You should be able to assign your string to a variable/constant before calling the callback, and passing in a reference to your string.

Comment: (error, { body } = {})

This is the callback function, it is getting stored as a body.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. You may need to share the whole implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/gauravmnnit/weather-website

it is the github of whole project src/utils/forecast

Comment: Instead of putting the string literal in the call to the callback function `callback(undefined, "my string")`, define the string constant first using backticks `const myString = \`foo\`;`, then pass a reference to it in to the callback `callback(undefined, myString)`.