# Javascript: Proper way to insert a newline in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript string newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character)

I am aware that `\n` is the newline character but it does not work for IE. I have to use `\r` to get it to work for IE. Is there a javascript or JQuery function to insert a newline no matter the browser type?

Comment: `\n` has always worked for me in IE.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an HTML element `$("#myelement").append('<br />')`;

If you are in a textarea `$("#mytextarea").append('\n')`;

It's a very obvious answer, tell you if it works or not.

Comment: I have tried \n in explorer but it does not work. I have to use \r to force it to go to the next line

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\r\n` which is the windows newline. It should work in Linux and Unix as well though.