# Why are new lines not working in this javascript alert window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

I see quite a few different issues with the alert window and new lines. Most are that the `\n` is considered a new line in PHP rather than getting sent to javascript.

In my case, the string is being outputted in a new window showing `\n`. I just tried actually writing `\n` into an alert box via jsfiddle, and that worked, so it must be my method of doing things...

Here is the string returned to console. as you can see, the \n is definitely there:

`Username is required\nPassword is required\nEmail is required\nPhone is required\nCardnumber is required`

However, it shows up like this:

[image: An alert with \n instead of a new line]

Why is this happening? I think it may have something to do with the data type, as it is returned from `$.ajax`

```
if (canAjax && !try_ajax) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "mobilesubmit.php",
        data: {"use_ajax": true, "formdata": $("#register_form").first().serializeArray()},
        success: function(data) {

            // This stupid thing should make new lines!
            alert(data);

            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            try_ajax = true;
            $("#register_form").submit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: See this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your console log is showing `\n` rather than a new line, then it means the `\` is escaped in the original string...

### Compare

```
console.log(1,"\\n\\n");
console.log(2,"\n\n");
```

### Solution

use `.replace()` to swap your `\n` with newline characters

```
console.log(3,"\\n\\n".replace(/\\n/g,"\n"))
```

Comment: Hah, that's probably it. You posted that while I was writing a wall of text that described the same thing. I'll delete my answer and mark this as correct. This was the issue all along. (I assumed chrome's console would not parse the new line. I'm still not sure where the extra slash is coming from - unless that's standard for ajax return results.)

Answer (score 4):

The most likely cause of this is that your PHP code is escaping the backslash by adding another backslash in front of it. By the time it gets to your JS code, it's actually

```
"Username is required\\nPassword is required..."
```

You can inspect the raw response in the network panel of your debugger. If you try to view it in the console, it'll display the formatted output instead of the raw output.

Double-check your method of JSON serialization in your PHP code and make sure it's doing what you expect with the \n.

Comment: "If you try to view it in the console, it'll display the formatted output instead of the raw output." That is what was giving me issues. You nailed it, but Billy Moon had it just before you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try adding a  space after \n .It should work

Comment: Nope, also tried putting the spacing before the \n, and again with a space on both sides. It's getting printed as-is rather than the tag getting parsed into a new line (if that's the correctly terminology).

Comment: Did u try adding <br /> tag just for reference?

Answer (score 0):

IE11 inspect shows the same problem on an asp.net generated hiddenfield - it 
    displays its value as value="test line 1\ntest line 2"

UT actually contains `value="test line 1\\ntest line 2"`

Using the `element.value.replace(/\\n/g,"\n")`
    on it then displays the correct line spaced string in a javascript `alert()`

Thanks Billy - saved hours of grief

Answer (score 0):

Do not use -> \n

Use this   -> \\n

example

```js
alert('Hello Wrold Second line \n\nThanks!') 

// if only above one ddoesn't work use below one!

alert('Hello Wrold Second line \\n\\nThanks!') 
//<!-- Publisher - Bathila Sanvidu Jayasundara -->
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30538840)

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: Please explain why a double backslash works, and a single one not, otherwise this is nothing more than a code only answer.