# How to replace html tags with new line character in jquery + imagemagick?

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I am having a contenteditable div. So according to a very good [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220939/force-ie-contenteditable-element-to-create-line-breaks-on-enter-key-without-bre)
html tags are added on enter key press for different browsers. Now i want to replace these with a new line character and send it to imagemagick plugin to create a new line effect.
HOw can i do this with jquery on the client side.

I am trying to do this but not getting the result:

```
messageText1 = $("#templateIframe")
  .contents()
  .find("#dialog")
  .html()
  .replace(/<(?:.|)*?>/gm, '\\n')
  .replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');

alert(messageText1);
messageText = messageText1.replace(/\n{2}/g, '\\n');
alert(messageText1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967722/why-are-new-lines-not-working-in-this-javascript-alert-window)

```
messageText = $("#templateIframe")
.contents()
.find("#dialog")
.html()
.replace(/<(?:.|)*?>/gm, '\\n')
.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')
.replace(/\\n\\n/g,"\\n");

alert(messageText);
```