# How to render html in ajax alert on success using asp.net mvc and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have action result which sends content like below

```
 public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
       string mystring = //doing some thing

       return Content(mystring , "html");
    }
```

**client side**

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/MyController/MyAction",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: details,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != "") {
                    alert(response);
                }                

            }
        });
```

now My string or response from action what i am sending is (it can be more numbers like 1 , 2 ,3 dynamic )

```
"\\n 1: blah blah.\\n 2: blah blah"
```

and in the alert its coming as

```
  \n 1: blah blah.\n 2: blah blah
```

how to make the alert look like

```
1.blah blah.
2.blah blah.
```

Cant change anything in server side , change allowed only in client side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are new lines not working in this javascript alert window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967722/why-are-new-lines-not-working-in-this-javascript-alert-window)

Comment: `return Content(mystring , "html");` should really be `return Content(mystring , "text/plain");` Also the problem is with the server side, you're not sending down a new line you're sending down "\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update your client side code.**

Replace the response.

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "/MyController/MyAction",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "html",
         data: details,
         success: function (response) {
         if (response != "") {
            response = response.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
            alert(response);
            }                
        }});
```

Comment: @tripathy try this hope it helps you.