# Using Javascript to eliminate "enter" button with PHP function?

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript string newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character)

I'm a bit of a noob to PHP and JS and have a simple problem.  I want the table to appear as soon as a selection is made and remove the enter button completely.

http://projectrepresentme.com/testpage/

I have a PHP script generating the table using an if loop.

How can I eliminate the Enter button?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function(){
    $('form').submit();
  });
});
<script>
```

But change the slectors for real ids or class.

Comment: Your answer proved the most useful, but its still not working 100%.  For some reason, it can't pull the PHP.  It queries the PHP doc, but nothing is displayed?  Any advice?

http://projectrepresentme.com/testpage/

Comment: You need run this code every time that you update the page.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button a style of `visibility: hidden` and give the form an ID (I will be using `myForm` as the ID in my example), then use this Javascript (assuming jQuery):

```
$('#myForm select').change(function(){
    $('#myForm input').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the visibility tip.  I'm 95% there.  Any idea why I can't get the PHP to display now?  http://projectrepresentme.com/testpage/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a java-script library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to help. Once jQuery is part of your page you can add:

```
$('#formID input').hide(); //hides the "enter" button
$('#formID select').change(function(){ 
  //submits the form when a selection is made
  $('#formID').submit();
});
```