# Getting the platform specific newline character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, newline

Years ago, I wrote the following function for one of my Firefox add-ons which helps me obtain a platform specific newline character:

```
GetNewLine: function()
{
    var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();

    if(platform.indexOf('win') != -1) // Windows
        return "\r\n";
    else if(platform.indexOf('mac') != -1) // Mac
        return "\r";
    else // *nix
        return "\n";
}
```

This seems to work OK, but upon reading the [newline Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), I noted that recent Apple operating systems (OS X and later) now use the UNIX style `\n` line ending. As such, my little function may be returning the wrong thing for that case (I don't have a Mac OS on which to test it).

**Is there a way I can get Firefox to tell me what the platform-specific newline character is?** Perhaps some sort of built-in utility function? I'm using these newlines in the text files my extension writes, and I want to use the platform specific one, so that the files look appropriate across various systems.

**Update (2-13-2013):** So upon running the `navigator.platform.toLowerCase()` function call on a Mac-mini (OS X), I get the output value `macintel`. This would result in my function returning `\r` instead of `\n` as it should.

Comment: Not my answer but a smart one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1156388/1883464

Comment: There is an API ([nsLinebreakConverter.cpp](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsLinebreakConverter.cpp) [nsLinebreakConverter.h](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsLinebreakConverter.h)), but as you can see it's outdated, and more importantly it is for internal use only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
GetNewLine: function()
{
    var OS = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1"].
             getService(Components.interfaces.nsIXULRuntime).OS;

    return /winnt|os2/i.test(OS) ? "\r\n" : /mac/i.test(OS) ? "\r" : "\n";
}
```

I'm pretty sure the "mac" case should never happen, seeing as it's not listed as a possibility in the [OS TARGET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/OS_TARGET) variable (which I'm testing via the `OS` property in `nsIXULRuntime`).

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 1/16/15: encoding does not handle os specific new line character.

from irc:

```
07:49   futpib  i guess encoding is for charset only
07:49   Will    character encoding is nothing to do with OS-specific line-endings
```

<strike>If you use OS.File and the TextEncoder it encodes your \n to os appropriate (im pretty sure):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread</strike>

```
let encoder = new TextEncoder();                                   // This encoder can be reused for several writes
let array = encoder.encode("This is some text");                   // Convert the text to an array
let promise = OS.File.writeAtomic("file.txt", array,               // Write the array atomically to "file.txt", using as temporary
    {tmpPath: "file.txt.tmp"});                                    // buffer "file.txt.tmp".
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any determining if you just want to split the text on newlines, you could do something like this:

```
htmlstring = sNewLine.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br>");
```

If you need the underlying webservers newline, you can get it with an Ajax call and return something like this if using ASP.NET

```
Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not generating any HTML (it's a simple plain-text file), and I'm interested in the *client* side's newline character (i.e. the OS in which Firefox is being run).