# Determine OS newline in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, newline

I am generating a file for the user to download, and I want to insert the correct newline character(s) for their platform (`\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`).

I am aware of the following solutions, but none solve my problem exactly:

- Querying `navigator.platform` or `navigator.appVersion`. These properties are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion), so I would prefer not to rely on them.
- There are specific approaches for [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22664158/2683771) and [NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12989543/2683771). These do not apply, as I'm creating a website, and I would prefer if it worked on all browsers.
- There are ways to find [the *browser's* newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556867/2683771), but I'm interested in the user's platform. (These are different: Firefox always uses `\n`, regardless of the OS.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character

Comment: @ub3rst4r That question is about the browser's newline character, not the underlying platform.

Comment: @Kaiido That property seems to be supported [only by Firefox](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlhiaix.php).

Comment: Actually, I can't find where else than in this mdn document it is said that `navigator.platform` is deprecated, it's not in the [Living](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-navigator-platform) [Standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#dom-navigator-platform)

Comment: Well to confirm this I should ask the mdn guys why they said so ( probably related to [this proposal](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27820) but can't be sure though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little investigation, I can't find anywhere else than in the linked [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion), it is said that `navigator.platform` is deprecated.

Both [WHATWG specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-navigator-platform) and [W3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#dom-navigator-platform) still include it in their Living Standards and there is no note about deprecation.

Actually, the w3 working group [asked in January to Firefox team](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27820) to remove `navigator.oscpu` or [to make it an alias](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27820#c4) to `navigator.platform` since the former is only implemented by this browser.

Note : The mdn page states that it is deprecated since [September 2, 2014](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform$compare?locale=en-US&to=660297&from=507097) but I'm not sure what motivated this edit though.

Anyway, I think that you can safely use this `navigator.platform` property to determine which OS the user is running on (bearing in mind that these informations can be spoofed by user, but then it's their problem isn't it?)

### Edit

Got a response from @Teoli who made this edit back in 2014 :
Question :

> Why navigator.platform is marked as deprecated on
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform
>   … ?

Answer :

> Because the spec asked browser vendor to put as few info in
>   it to avoid fingerprinting. Putting '' would be spec. Don't rely on
>   it.

[Link to the mentioned specs request.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#client-identification:fingerprinting-vector)

Comment: Worth to be noted that he agreed the whole ClientIdentification API should have this header (`navigator.userAgent` included).

Answer (score 3):

Parsing `navigator.userAgent` might be a reasonably reliable way of detecting OS and hence which newline character to use.

Something along the lines of would probably do the trick - might need some tweaking on UA strings that are tested for the individual platforms.

Also it wouldn't work if the UA is spoofed.

```
function getLinebreak (){
    var linebreaks =  {
        Windows: "\r\n", 
        Mac: "\n", 
        Linux: "\n"
    }
    for(key in linebreaks){
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf(key) != -1){
            return linebreaks[key];
        }
    }
    return "\n"; 
}
```

Note: you could probably safely only check if it's Windows otherwise return \n in most cases

Something like this would likely work in most cases too:

```
function getLinebreak(){
  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") != -1){
    return "\r\n";
  }
  return "\n";
}
```