# How to split string with newline ('\n') in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Within Node, how do I split a string using newline ('\n') ?
I have a simple string like `var a = "test.js\nagain.js"` and I need to get `["test.js", "again.js"]`.
I tried

```
a.split("\n");
a.split("\\n");
a.split("\r\n");
a.split("\r");
```

but the above doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript string newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character)

Comment: [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) doesn't modify the original string.

Comment: This looks like a pure JavaScript question, not requiring a node.js tag.

Comment: @Wyck, it's useful to know that Node is the intended runtime, because the `newline` character in a string is often platform-dependent. In Node.js, it's very common to operate on file texts with `newline` characters, and it's important to know the platform. In a browser context, this this less of an issue. But I would suggest the OP change the question to specify the target environment, or else ask for solutions that work generically on all major platforms.

Answer (score 340):

Try splitting on a regex like `/\r?\n/` to be usable by both Windows and UNIX systems.

```javascript
> "a\nb\r\nc".split(/\r?\n/)
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Comment: What about classic Macs? ;)

Comment: classic Macs died along with Steve Jobs... sadness :(

Comment: to catch \n, \r and \r\n: `split(/[\r\n]+/)`

Comment: MacOSX don't use single \r anymore, that was only for old Macs. I think they have the same \n as other unixes.

Comment: How can .split(/\r?\n/) be changed to support any number of "\r\n" or "\n"? In other words if I have a string "The\r\n\r\nquick\r\n\r\nbrown\r\nfox\r\njumps\r\n\r\nover" how to change regex above to get just [quick, brown, fox, jumps, over]?

Comment: I just tried .split(/[\r?\n]+/) and that seems to work for splitting if you have multiple consecutive line breaks such as "\r\n\r\n..." or "\n\n..." - hope I got that correct.

Comment: You don't need the `?`. `[\r\n]` is a regex *character set*, which means it can match `\r` or `\n`. `split(/[\r\n]+/)` would work.

Comment: /[\r\n]+/ will filter out empty lines

Answer (score 64):

If the file is native to your system (certainly no guarantees of that), then Node can help you out:

```
var os = require('os');

a.split(os.EOL);
```

This is usually more useful for constructing *output* strings from Node though, for platform portability.

Comment: Yeah, you generally shouldn't do this. You should parse newlines regardless of the platform.

Comment: I highlight that this is specifically for the case of files native to your system in the very first sentence. The answer above is appropriate for when this is unknown or mixed.

Comment: Right. Or when it's "known" now but might change in the future.

Comment: only works when loading files on the platform they were created on.

Comment: Good for temp files(?)

Answer (score 57):

It looks like regex `/\r\n|\r|\n/` handles CR, LF, and CRLF line endings, their mixed sequences, and keeps all the empty lines inbetween. Try that!

```js
    function splitLines(t) { return t.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/); }

    // single newlines
    console.log(splitLines("AAA\rBBB\nCCC\r\nDDD"));
    // double newlines
    console.log(splitLines("EEE\r\rFFF\n\nGGG\r\n\r\nHHH"));
    // mixed sequences
    console.log(splitLines("III\n\r\nJJJ\r\r\nKKK\r\n\nLLL\r\n\rMMM"));
```

You should get these arrays as a result:

```js
[ "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" ]
[ "EEE", "", "FFF", "", "GGG", "", "HHH" ]
[ "III", "", "JJJ", "", "KKK", "", "LLL", "", "MMM" ]
```

You can also teach that regex to recognize other legit [Unicode line terminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) by adding `|\xHH` or `|\uHHHH` parts, where `H`'s are hexadecimal digits of the additional terminator character codepoint (as seen in Wikipedia article as `U+HHHH`).

Answer (score 40):

```
a = a.split("\n");
```

---

Note that `split`ting returns the new array, rather than just assigning it to the original string. You need to explicitly store it in a variable.

Comment: Doesn't work on windows. i'm seeing 'r' on every end of a line.

Answer (score 21):

A solution that works with all possible line endings including 
mixed ones and keeping empty lines as well can be achieved using
two replaces and one split as follows

```
text.replace(/\r\n/g, "\r").replace(/\n/g, "\r").split(/\r/);
```

some code to test it

```
  var CR = "\x0D";  //   \r
  var LF = "\x0A";  //   \n

  var mixedfile = "00" + CR + LF +            // 1 x win
                  "01" + LF +                 // 1 x linux
                  "02" + CR +                 // 1 x old mac
                  "03" + CR + CR +            // 2 x old mac
                  "05" + LF + LF +            // 2 x linux
                  "07" + CR + LF + CR + LF +  // 2 x win
                  "09";

  function showarr (desc, arr)
  {
     console.log ("// ----- " + desc);
     for (var ii in arr)
        console.log (ii + ") [" + arr[ii] +  "] (len = " + arr[ii].length + ")");
  }

  showarr ("using 2 replace + 1 split", 
           mixedfile.replace(/\r\n/g, "\r").replace(/\n/g, "\r").split(/\r/));
```

and the output

```
  // ----- using 2 replace + 1 split
  0) [00] (len = 2)
  1) [01] (len = 2)
  2) [02] (len = 2)
  3) [03] (len = 2)
  4) [] (len = 0)
  5) [05] (len = 2)
  6) [] (len = 0)
  7) [07] (len = 2)
  8) [] (len = 0)
  9) [09] (len = 2)
```

Comment: Actually the solution given by blakkwater:
       text.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
do the same and it is shorter and faster

Answer (score 10):

The first one should work:

```
> "a\nb".split("\n");
[ 'a', 'b' ]
> var a = "test.js\nagain.js"
undefined
> a.split("\n");
[ 'test.js', 'again.js' ]
```

Answer (score 4):

I made an [`eol` module](https://github.com/ryanve/eol#api) for working with line endings in node or browsers. It has a split method like

```
var lines = eol.split(text)
```