# Converting byte array to string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using ssh2 to execute ls -1 command on remote computer and get response like byte array.
I convert to string with function

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
```

but when I try to split resulted/converted string by newline it doesn't work. (I have tried and asked on stackoverflow how to split and tried all solutions but it doesn't work, different results like add \ at the beginning and similar but doesn't split). I think maybe I convert on wrong way. Did anyone use ssh2 for return and how to convert that array to string.

Comment: Your title, code and question do not at all match.  What do you want?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195865/converting-byte-array-to-string-in-javascript

Comment: I think you have to show your code, because I tried what you said, and it worked fine. The code you did post is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Buffer.toString()](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method on your buf

Answer (score 0):

You might try Node's implementation of the standard [Web Crypto API](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html) which includes the `TextDecoder()` method for converting byte arrays into strings.

In terms of splitting strings on newline characters, there are several good examples of this on StackOverflow, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895233/how-to-split-string-with-newline-n-in-node).

The TextDecorder method is illustrated pretty well [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder).

> ```
> let utf8decoder = new TextDecoder(); // default 'utf-8' or 'utf8'
>
> let u8arr = new Uint8Array([240, 160, 174, 183]);
> let i8arr = new Int8Array([-16, -96, -82, -73]);
> let u16arr = new Uint16Array([41200, 47022]);
> let i16arr = new Int16Array([-24336, -18514]);
> let i32arr = new Int32Array([-1213292304]);
>
> console.log(utf8decoder.decode(u8arr));
> console.log(utf8decoder.decode(i8arr));
> console.log(utf8decoder.decode(u16arr));
> console.log(utf8decoder.decode(i16arr));
> console.log(utf8decoder.decode(i32arr));
> ```