# Split 2 or more new lines into sentences using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split 2 or more new lines in JavaScript.

For example,

```
Hello
\n
Don't split me
\n
\n
But split me since I am 2 or more lines below
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
You can also split me since I am 6 lines below
```

should result in

## 1

```
Hello

Don't split me
```

## 2

```
But split me since I am 2 or more lines below
```

## 3

```
You can also split me since I am 6 lines below
```

Basically removing all `\n`.

I tried doing `str.split(/\r?\n/)` but it splits for single-line. I want it to do for 2 or more lines but it must work for CR, LF, and CRLF line endings.

I did see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947649/6141587 but it only does for single-line as well. Literally, every answer is for a single-line break which I know how to do.

I want it to work for 2 or more new lines.

How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Edit your question to include the code you've written so far to meet this requirement (as a [mre]) along with an explanation of where *specifically* you're getting stuck (including all error messages and other pertinent debugging information) in accordance with [ask].

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. *(not my downvote)*

Comment: @esqew & TJ added a description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take full advantage of JavaScript String methods `split()` and `trim()` with some basic Regex:

```
const input =
"Hello\nDon't split me\n\nBut split me since I am 2 or more lines below\n\n\n\n\n\nYou can also split me since I am 6 lines below";

const re = new RegExp(/(\n){2,}|(\r\n){2,}|(\r){2,}/);
const output = input.split(re);

for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    output[i] = output[i].trim();
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can you edit it to work for [CR, LF, and CRLF line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552782/6141587)?

Comment: Ok, just edited it.  Will split on 2+ '\n' or 2+ '\r\n' or 2+ '\r'.