# How to pass a double value into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to pass double values into a JavaScript array:

```
var a = 15,2;
var tab = [a];
```

In fact, I'm trying to do not change `a`'s value directly, but I need to deal it implicitly. (in my app the a's value is generated dynamically so I can't explicitly change its comma)

This table should have only one cell, but it's taking two cells.

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: JavaScript numeric constants use `.` as the fraction separator, not `,`.

Comment: That's not a double. The decimal point should be a dot (`.`): `15.2`.

Comment: BTW, I don't see how it take two cells : this is a syntax error.

Comment: It's taking two cells? What are you talking about? `var a = 15,2;` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Number literals use a dot (`.`) as the decimal point:

```
var a = 15.2;
//        ^------ dot (.), not comma (,)
var tab = [a];
```

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to do not change `a`'s value directly, but I need to deal it implicitly.

Comment: What do you mean? This doesn't change a's value from anything : your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: in my app the `a`'s value is generated dynamically so I can't explicitly change its comma.

Comment: Well, you can't have `var a = 15,2;` in your code, apart in a string.

Comment: well than you have a problem @ABCmo.

Comment: @ABCmo Generated how? Surely not as a number, because that would have the `.` instead of `,`. If it is generated as a String `"15,2"` you can just replace the comma by a dot and `parseFloat`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers, I'm building an ASP.NET MVC web-app, so, I'm sending from Controllor a double value with `15,2` to finally display it into the View. [You can find more details about my code, here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273992/how-to-make-a-foreach-loop-into-javascript)

Comment: That other question and answer are based on a terrible practice. Don't generate JS code from ASP ! You should generate data in a standard exchange format (JSON comes to mind) and then (client side) insert those data where necessary.