# \n not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason \n isn't working for me in javascript. Is there anyway to fix it or use html? In my case, I think that using `<br>` will not work in my href. What are your suggestions.

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7q4cq/4/).

HTML:

```
<a id = 'emailoff' href = "" target = "_blank">
    <div id= "btn1">
        <h2 id = "enter">Send Email</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    $("#emailoff").attr("href", "mailto:" +
        "?subject=Your ThinOptics glasses" +
        "&body=To get your new ThinOptics glasses simply click this link and pick the case and color you like best.  You'll get  free shipping on your order. \n"+
        " WWw.Thinoptics.Com/teddy@shalon.com \n" +
        "\n Enjoy")
});
```

Comment: `\n` does work in JavaScript. But your problem is that the href gets multilined what you properly wants is to escape the new line so the mail client gets `\n` and can treat it as `\n`: TLDR: Use `\\n` but the support can differ from client to client.

Comment: this might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character

Comment: @NULL "\\n" doesn't seem to be working... do you mean replacing "\n" with "\\n"?

Comment: You are not inserting anything dynamically at all in your href, so why not just insert the href attribute when rendering the page?

Comment: Try %0D instead of \n

Comment: @epascarello It's true, but the OP wouldn't have known to search for that, they were under the impression that the problem was JS escaping. I would leave it open so that others can find the answer in case they don't understand the problem well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to URL encode your new lines. The encoded new line should be  `%0A` http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/LSUAh/

```
<a id = 'emailoff' href = "mailto:me@you.com?subject=hello&body=a%0Ab" target = "_blank">
    <div id= "btn1">
        <h2 id = "enter">Send Email</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

If you're doing it in JS, use the following

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    $("#emailoff").attr("href", "mailto:" +
        "?subject=Your ThinOptics glasses" +
        "&body=To get your new ThinOptics glasses simply click this link and pick the case and color you like best.  You'll get  free shipping on your order. %0A"+
         " WWw.Thinoptics.Com/teddy@shalon.com  %0A" +
        " %0A Enjoy")
});
```

Note that you don't have to hardcode the URL encoded version, you can use

```
encodeURIComponent("\n") // %0A
```

P.S. Wouldn't it be better not to rely on the user's mail client being configured? Use your own server to send the email instead to make sure all users can send a message.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.. I can see the spring break is all ready slowing me down :)

Comment: I also have another small question... if I want to put the url there in a hyperlink to that url, how do I do that? For some reason, the link isn't working...

Comment: @LiamShalon Please create a separate question. At SO, we like questions to be about a single thing. That way, the question is more useful to others. Feel free to link to it here and tag me on it so I'm notified. I think I know the answer but it will be much easier when you create a new question showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<br>
```

instead of

```
 \n
```

\n is rendered as 1 space in html and so is \t or \s

Comment: This won't work with text based email clients

Comment: it works with %0D instead of \n

Comment: Actually this won't work at all because [the specification for mailto](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) says that it's to be used with text based email only, therefore, the <br> would be rendered as is, instead of as a line break. `The "body" hname should contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the message.`