# Javascript Newline Character Throwing Error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, textbox

I am having trouble getting some data from a textbox using javascript. What I am trying to do is take the value from a textbox and put it in an alert and copy it. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
var copyString = "Date: <%= TXT_Details_DateReq.Text %>;
window.prompt('Press CTRL+C, then ENTER\n\nNOTE: SAVE ANY CHANGES BEFORE COPYING TEXT!', copyString); return false;
```

So this code works perfectly fine if the text in the textbox is just one line. But if the text in the textbox has multiple lines such as:

```
"This is one line
here is a second line"
```

The code will throw the error `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL`.
From what I have researched this throws when there is an illegal character, so I believe it is the CRLF character from the textbox.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What am I supposed to replace?

Comment: The newline with it escaped version - `\n` (or `Environment.NewLine`) -> `\\n`

Comment: But I am passing it a textbox value so I won't be able to know where the \n is in the value.

Comment: What do you mean by "textbox"?  Is it an `<input>` element or a `<textarea>` element?

Comment: It is a `<asp: TextBox>` control

Comment: _so I won't be able to know where the \n is in the value_ - You haven't read the documentation...? `<textbox>.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\n")`

Comment: Yes I read it, I was just confused. This did work though. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

New line characters might be preceded by return characters (`'\r'`).

Swap `'\n'` with `'\r\n'` and you should be good to go.

Or even better: just handle all cases of the new line character instead of checking which case then applying it.  This replace the newline:

```
htmlstring = stringContainingNewLines.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br>");
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character/8956449#8956449)

hope it helps.

Comment: This is for Javascript. The text with the newline is from a server control, so the value has to be replaced on the server and not on the client. Furthermore a `<br />` tag won't work at all in a prompt.

Comment: The main tag on the OP _is_ Javascript.

Comment: And how you think you can fix the `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL` error in the Javascript part with Javascript?!