# Get Newline character using javascript

Tags: javascript

In my html page I have to split user input based on newline character.
How to get newline character using javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript string newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character)

Comment: sorry i dont get you properly....can you explain....?

Comment: check the question linked to find existing answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The resume of [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character) is using `regex` does allow you to ignore the `OS` you're using:

> I don't think you really need to do much of any determining, though. If you just want to split the text on newlines, you could do something like this:

```
lines = foo.value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);
```

**In your case:**

```
var splittedValues = originalTxt.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);
```

Comment: i did same splitting in java...but it was working in my local system and not working in live...because linux new line character is different from windows...           thats why i tried to get new line char and split based on that...     Thanks....

Comment: the code I posted must work on windows, linux and macOS

Comment: my code is working in windows but not working in linux system                                        var splittedValues = originalTxt.split('\n');

Comment: your code is not correct, please, **read the answers and the duplicate question**....

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code :

var str=document.getElementById('nwline').value;

var lines = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);

```
console.log(lines);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/0yog7v83/

Comment: i am not sure javascript newline character is \n in all Operating System...thats why i asked...