# Need help styling on javascript

Tags: javascript, styling

```
var stateData = {
     MA: { fullName: 'Massachusetts: some  infor here | some info here | test'}, 
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia:' },
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' },
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' },
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' },
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' },
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' },
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' },
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' }
    // other states' data...
}
```

I need help styling the code inside MA, it does not let me put line breaks or anything. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this post is a bit too length for the comment box.

`\n` is [the universal newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1155681).

But perhaps you should look at this alternative:

```
var stateData = {
    MA: {
        fullName: 'Massachusetts',
        motto: 'A catchy expression here',
        information: 'More data here',
        population: 1000
    },
}
```

To me it looks like you are building some JSON that you'll probably reference like:

```
stateData.MA.fullName
```

It's considered bad practice to format your raw data. You should probably do this when you use the data:

```
console.log('Now you\'ve travelled to: ' + stateData.MA.fullName + "/n" + stateData.MA.motto);
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a line break within a JavaScript string then you should do \n (which stands for new line)

Comment: Are you putting the \n inside the quotes? Such as 'Virginia \n'?

Comment: It's hard to make suggestions not knowing the rest of your code. JavaScript itself has no display.