# Embedding a new line character in a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, newline

The embedded "\n" characters in the following code does NOT produce line breaks in the generated string. What am I to do??? :-)

```
/* Load array into DOM */
var directory = document.getElementById ("directory");
directory.innerHTML = "";
var numberOfHouses = house.length;
for (i = 0; i < numberOfHouses; i++) {
    var houseNode = document.createElement('span');
    var text = (house[i][0] + "\n" + house[i][1] + "\n" + house[i][2] + "\n" + house[i][3] + "\n " + house[i][4] + "\n" + house[i][5] + "\n" + house[i][6] + "\n" + house[i][7] + "\n" + house[i][8] + "\n\n");
    var houseText = document.createTextNode(text);
    houseNode.appendChild(houseText);
    directory.appendChild(houseNode);       
  }
```

Comment: The string data outputs, but not with embedded line breaks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character.   If you are ultimately writing the string to html you can use the br tag to create line breaks.  Remember that HTML collapses whitespace including line breaks by default.

Answer (score 1):

That's because a linefeed in a text node does not render as a linefeed.

If you want a linefeed on a web page, you need to use CSS such as `white-space: pre-line;` to make them count, or add a `<br>` element

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `<br>`  to make the new lines.  You are creating the string in javascript, but it is being interpreted in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
var directory = document.getElementById ("directory");
directory.innerHTML = "";
var numberOfHouses = house.length;
for (row = 0; row < numberOfHouses; row++) {
  var houseNode = document.createElement('span');
  for (column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
    var text = (house[row][column]);
    var houseText = document.createTextNode(text);
    houseNode.appendChild(houseText);
    directory.appendChild(houseNode);
    var brNode = document.createElement ('br');
    houseNode.appendChild(brNode);
  }
  var pNode = document.createElement('p');
  directory.appendChild(pNode);
}
```

// Fixed!