# trouble turning file into array and then outputting object value

Tags: javascript, node.js

The goal of my application is simple:

- Accept a random number parameter
- Read the dictionary.txt file
- turn that file into an array by taking each word in the file (each word is on a new line in the file)
- push each array item created into an object and then have itself as a word property

At the point I have the object created, my aim is to get a random word from that object, for example:

```
outputObj[randNum].word
```

Which should return the word at the index I set in the randNum parameter and the value stored in its word property.

I am getting confused and have tried everything I can think of to achieve the end result.

Here is my current JS:

```
var fs = require('fs),
    getWordFromRandomNumber = function(randNum) {
        var output = fs.readFileSync('../dictionary/dictionary.txt', 'utf8')
            .trim()
            .split('\r\n')
            .map(line => line.split('\r\n'))
            .reduce(function(outputObj, line){
            outputObj[line] =  outputObj[line] || [];
            outputObj[line].push({
                word: line,
            });
            return outputObj[randNum].word;
        }, {});


        console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
    }

getWordFromRandomNumber(25);
```

I expect this to return to me the value of outputObj[25].word but all I get is a cascade of the whole file, see here (note I am using my cmd to run the file using babel and node with the command "babel wordGenerator.js | node":

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated as I am all out of ideas at the moment.

Thanks,
SD

Comment: you should be splitting by \r\n not /n

Comment: fixed that as you can now see but still not returning what I want it to.

Comment: `babel` is a *"Python internationalization library with an emphasis on web-based applications."*... are you really using that library? I don't imagine it works on JavaScript files.

Comment: it does, it is an emulator for js files in node, I use it all the time and it is never an issue, all it does is output console.logs into the cmd, it could do more but thats all I use it for anyhow.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `babeljs`: *"Babel (formerly 6to5) is a JavaScript compiler. It transforms ES6+/ES2015 code into ES5 code."* ?

Comment: there is more than one babel? I never knew. but yeah, babeljs: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: Also I don't think you are fully aware of how reduce works. Check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Always read the tag description. The one for `babel` is *"Python internationalization library with an emphasis on web-based applications. For questions about the JavaScript library, please use [babeljs]."* Either way, this doesn't have anything to with babel itself, so it doesn't even make sense to tag it. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel .

Comment: I didnt realise, will do next time. Still, my issue still stands and its quite annoying because I can't figure it out still.

Comment: Ugh, where did you get a \r\n delimited text file? :-(

Comment: from the pits of hell itself I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my application working perfect now, the issue was fixed by using ajax instead of nodes fs.

Now I have this:

```
var getDictionaryFile = function(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", file, false);
    xhr.send(null);
    var returnValue = xhr.responseText;
    return returnValue;
},
getWordFromRandomNumber = function(randNum, el) {  
        var target = document.querySelectorAll(el),
            output = getDictionaryFile("../dictionary/dictionary.txt")
        .trim()
        .split('\r\n');

        [].forEach.call(output, function(line) {
            if(output[randNum % output.length - 1] == line ){
                [].forEach.call(target, function(element) {
                    element.innerHTML = line;
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

And the response text is doing the same thing as the last code except working, ie: being read, split into an array, looped over and then the index I want is decided by a random number. Thus, I get a random word with each request as expected.

Comment: Are you using Node server-side ??? i don't understand why you decide to put this part on client side !

Comment: this is pureJS, no node in this answer. What are you on about?

Comment: pureJS meaning pure javascript, ie: no frameworks, plain, simple JS only.

Comment: When i told Node i was talking about Node.js ! ! server-side ! you have put the tag [[node.js]], you use `var fs = require('fs')` and at last you talk about ajax, so i don't understand ! ??

Comment: My original questions had an issue. At the time of the question I used node. Then I fixed my issue by using `XHR` instead of `fs`. and altering what is returned by the `getRandomWordFromNumber` function.

Answer (score 0):

If the file really has all individual words on a new line (your output suggests something else) then the following should suffice:

```
var output = fs.readFileSync('../dictionary/dictionary.txt', 'utf8')
  .trim() // to remove whitespace
  .split('\r')   // creates array with individual words
  .map(item => { return { word :item } }); // creates array with objects
return output[randNum % output.length].word;
```

No need to do reduce or create another outobject.

This code should work with valid input, where words are separated by '\r'. The output suggest words are separated by '\r\n' or '\r\'. This creates words with '\r'. If you want words without '\r', you should apply some regex to flush that out. Maybe change into `.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);` will do the trick.

PS: the % part is to ensure that if randNum input is larger than the array length, you do not get error output. Array is created inside the function, so when called, it is still unclear what the maximum valid number actually will be.

Comment: tried your code and it is just throwing an error of "cannot read property of word of undefined"

Comment: I suspect it breaks down at the start because of the input file. What is the output if you `console.log(fs.readFileSync('../dictionary/dictionary.txt', 'utf8'))` ?

Comment: returns the text in the file, on new lines as it reads if I opened it in txt format

Comment: OK, small steps..so what does `console.log(fs.readFileSync('../dictionary/dictionary.txt', 'utf8')).trim()` output?

Comment: the same, all trim does is remove excess whitespace if any.

Comment: OK, next: what does `console.log(fs.readFileSync('../dictionary/dictionary.txt', 'utf8')).split['\r']` output?

Comment: it looks for the \r special char in the file and splits the file between each, thus each word on each line becomes an array property

Comment: Have you actually tested this? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character) I found that it should actually be more like `.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);`

Comment: same result, mostly because there are no single \r or \n chars, its always \r\n at the end of the lines and so that is why I have ti set as \r\n only at the moment

Comment: Hmm, does `console.log(output[1]);`(before your return statement) give you any sensible output? Expect `{ word : '' }` Perhaps you could update your question with latest version of your code? Or share fiddle? (can look at it again tomorrow)

Answer (score 0):

One solution possible :

```js
var str = " line_0\r\nline_1\r\nline_2\r\nline_3\r\nline_4\r\nline_5\r\nline_6\r\nline_7\r\nline_8\r\nline_9\r\nline_10\r\nline_11\r\nline_12\r\nline_13\r\nline_14\r\nline_15\r\nline_16\r\nline_17\r\nline_18\r\nline_19\r\nline_20\r\nline_21\r\nline_22\r\nline_23\r\nline_24\r\nline_25\r\nline_26\r\nline_27\r\nline_28\r\nline_29\r\nline_30\r\nline_31\r\nline_32\r\nline_33\r\nline_34\r\nline_35\r\nline_36\r\nline_37\r\nline_38\r\nline_39\r\nline_40\r\nline_41\r\nline_42\r\nline_43\r\nline_44\r\nline_45\r\nline_46\r\nline_47\r\nline_48\r\nline_49\r\nline_50\r\nline_51\r\nline_52\r\nline_53\r\nline_54\r\nline_55\r\nline_56\r\nline_57\r\nline_58\r\nline_59\r\nline_60\r\nline_61\r\nline_62\r\nline_63\r\nline_64\r\nline_65\r\nline_66\r\nline_67\r\nline_68\r\nline_69\r\nline_70\r\nline_71\r\nline_72\r\nline_73\r\nline_74\r\nline_75\r\nline_76\r\nline_77\r\nline_78\r\nline_79\r\nline_80\r\nline_81\r\nline_82\r\nline_83\r\nline_84\r\nline_85\r\nline_86\r\nline_87\r\nline_88\r\nline_89\r\nline_90\r\nline_91\r\nline_92\r\nline_93\r\nline_94\r\nline_95\r\nline_96\r\nline_97\r\nline_98\r\nline_99 ";

var arr = str
           .trim()
           .split("\r\n")
           .map(function(value , index){
             return { index: index , word : value}; 
           });


var len = arr.length;
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);

var result = arr[ randNum ].word;

document.body.innerHTML+= '<br> randNum = ' + randNum + ' result : ' + result ;
```

```html
Just click run again and again . . .
```

---

So your code become :

```
var fs = require('fs),
    getWordFromRandomNumber = function(randNum) {
        var output = fs.readFileSync('../dictionary/dictionary.txt', 'utf8')
           .trim()
           .split('\r\n')
           .map( val => { return {  word : val }; });

       console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
       return output[ randNum ].word;
   };

getWordFromRandomNumber(25);
```

Note that each time you call `getWordFromRandomNumber` you will read the dictionary file , split it , map it !
If your dictionary is static maybe you can 'cache' the result of process !

```
var fs = require('fs),
    cached = null ,
    getWordFromRandomNumber = function(randNum) {

       if(cached) return cached[ randNum ].word;

       var output = fs.readFileSync('../dictionary/dictionary.txt', 'utf8')
           .trim()
           .split('\r\n')
           .map( val => { return {  word : val }; });

       console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
       cached = output;
       return output[ randNum ].word;
   };

getWordFromRandomNumber(25);
```