# code breaks console.log()!

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand why I'm getting the output:

```
var frenchWords;
fs = require('fs')

var data = fs.readFileSync('frenchVerbsList.txt', 'utf8');
frenchWords = data.split('\n');
console.log(Array.isArray(frenchWords)); //true 

var x = frenchWords[0];
console.log("a: " + "look: " + x + typeof(x));
//outputs "stringk: abaisser"
```

I don't understand why the output isn't "a: look: abaisserstring"

Any explanation of what's going on will be gratefully received :-)

Gerard

Comment: Well, I just used your program and output is as expected. `a: look: abaisserstring`. What does your file `frenchVerbsList.txt` looks like? For me its new line separated words.

Comment: In case you wonder about \r and \n on different evironments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r Or about a browser solution instead of node: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1156388/146513

Comment: Not possible! Are you sure this is exactly  the code you are executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely happening because your file's lines of text are terminated by \r\n, not just \n as I can reproduce this with:

```
var x = 'abaisser\r';
console.log("a: " + "look: " + x + typeof (x));
```

This outputs `"stringk: abaisser"` because the CR (\r) char returns the output cursor back to the beginning of the line so that `string` overrwrites the previously output `a: loo` chars.

So try changing your `data.split` call to:

```
frenchWords = data.split('\r\n');
```

Or as Ismael suggested in the comments, use a regex that matches any of the common line terminations of CR, LF, or CRLF by using:

```
frenchWords = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/g)
```

Comment: Actually, use `data.split(/\r?\n|\r/g)`. There, no more problems with newlines. It works with `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`. Try this: `'a b ~\n test\r\n \r f'.split(/\r?\n|\r/g)` (should output `["a b ~", " test", " ", " f"]`)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Good idea -- added. Thanks.