# Can't get effect of "\n" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function myMap() {
 var addrlist = document.getElementById("addresslist");

 var jsaddr = "Address Line1 <br /> Address Line 2 <br /> Address Line 3";
 var addr = jsaddr.split("<br />"); 
 //alert(addr);
 var addrfinal = "";
 for(var j=0;j<addr.length;j++)
 {
      addrfinal = addrfinal + addr[j] + "\n";
 }
 alert(addrfinal);
    
 var traddr = document.createElement("tr");
 var tdaddr = document.createElement("td");
 var tdaddress = document.createTextNode(addrfinal);
 tdaddr.appendChild(tdaddress);
 traddr.appendChild(tdaddr);
 addrlist.appendChild(traddr);   
}
```

```html
<table id="addresslist">
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="myMap()" />
```

I want to add address to table line by line. But when I alert string it will get the effect of "\n", but in string I can't get the effect of "\n"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character
Try read this

But when dealing with html, use <br>

Comment: But when I add <br/> then it will write <br/> like Address Line 1 <br /> Address Line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add address to table line by line.

In that case you are just complicating things. All you need is to **use innerHTML property** on the `td` element and assign your initial string.

```
tdaddr.innerHTML = jsaddr;
```

Check the example below.

```js
function myMap() {
 var addrlist = document.getElementById("addresslist");

 var jsaddr = "Address Line1 <br /> Address Line 2 <br /> Address Line 3";      
  
 var traddr = document.createElement("tr");
 var tdaddr = document.createElement("td");
 
 tdaddr.innerHTML = jsaddr;  // this is the change
 traddr.appendChild(tdaddr);
 addrlist.appendChild(traddr);   
}
```

```html
<table id="addresslist">
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="myMap()" />
```

Comment: @RiddhiRathod glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `<br>` tag and assign line for line to the table element.

```js
function myMap() {
    var addrlist = document.getElementById("addresslist");
    var jsaddr = "Address Line1 <br /> Address Line 2 <br /> Address Line 3";
    var addr = jsaddr.split("<br />");
    var traddr = document.createElement("tr");
    var tdaddr = document.createElement("td");
    for (var j = 0; j < addr.length; j++) {
        if (j) {
            tdaddr.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        }
        tdaddr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addr[j]));
    }
    traddr.appendChild(tdaddr);
    addrlist.appendChild(traddr);
}
```

```html
<table id="addresslist"></table>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="myMap()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create rows inside the loop, see the follow script:

```js
function myMap() {
 var addrlist = document.getElementById("addresslist");

 var jsaddr = "Address Line1 <br /> Address Line 2 <br /> Address Line 3";
 var addr = jsaddr.split("<br />"); 
 //alert(addr);
 var addrfinal = "";
 for(var j=0;j<addr.length;j++)
 {
     addrfinal = addrfinal + addr[j] + "\n";
      
        var traddr = document.createElement("tr");
        var tdaddr = document.createElement("td");
        var tdaddress = document.createTextNode(addr[j]);
        tdaddr.appendChild(tdaddress);
        traddr.appendChild(tdaddr);
        addrlist.appendChild(traddr); 
 }
 alert(addrfinal);

}
```

```html
<table id="addresslist">
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="myMap()" />
```