# Can't escape new line in object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't escape a new line when it is in an object. I just did this in Node. Anyone have an idea how this can be done?

```
var result =  {
    key1: "This is a line\n with new\n lines\n.",
    key2: "No new lines here."
};
```

Here are my results:

> result
>   Object

```
var myTemp = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Here are the results

> ‌‌ myTemp
>   ‌ {"key1":"This is a line\n with new\n lines\n.","key2":"No new lines here."}

```
var newTemp = myTemp.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n");
```

Finally, here are the final results.

> ‌‌ newTemp
>   ‌ {"key1":"This is a line\n with new\n lines\n.","key2":"No new lines here."}

Notice how it is still `\n`, not `\\n`.

Comment: Why would you want to get `\\n`? That's not an escaped newline, that's an escaped backslash followed by an n character.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex needs to be escaped, too: `myTemp.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`

Reason:

- `\n` matches actual new line characters
- `\\n` matches the representation of a new line character given by the characters "\" followed by "n" as it can be found in the JSON string.

Answer (score -1):

Based on an answer on StackOverflow here: [JavaScript string newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character)

Below is the safest way to escape new lines:

```
var key1 = "This is a line\n with new\n lines\n.";
var k2 = key1.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,'');
```

Comment: This will actually remove the new line characters entirely, which is not the same as escaping them (almost opposite)!