# Javascript Textbox Copy/Paste Loss of Newline

Tags: javascript, css, tampermonkey

I have a Tampermonkey script that creates a list of values from checked checkboxes on a webpage. The box displays the data beautifully, each value on a new line below the other. However, I lose the newline characters when I copy and paste these values using Microsoft clipboard. Is there a way to adjust the script in order to allow preservation of the newline characters (`\n`)?

JavaScript:

```
var box = document.createElement( 'div' );
box.id = 'myAlertBox';

document.body.appendChild( box );

box.textContent = text + '\n';

var selectedQueries = document.querySelectorAll (query);

selectedQueries.forEach ( (chkBox) => {
    box.textContent += chkBox.title + '\n';
});
```

CSS:

```
#myAlertBox {
    font-size: small;
    background: white;
    border: 5px solid green;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px; right: 80px;
    max-width: 300px;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Newlines in windows are `\r\n`, so... you might find your answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character if so we can close as dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Comment: That is because `\n` is a line-break character, but remember that in HTML all whitespaces are treated as collapsible space (unless you set `white-space: pre`). If you want a line break in HTML, you will have to convert it to `<br />`. This can be done using regular expression.

Comment: The data is added as text content. Do I need to change from a text box to HTML content instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I simply changed `textContent` to `innerHTML` and used `<br/>` as the line breaks as suggested. You have all collectively saved me a lot of manual labor.

Working code:

```
function ParseCheckBoxes (query, text) {

    if (document.getElementById('myAlertBox') !== null) {
        document.getElementById("myAlertBox").outerHTML='';
    }

    var box = document.createElement( 'div' );
    box.id = 'myAlertBox';

    document.body.appendChild( box );

    box.innerHTML = text + '<br/>';

    var selectedQueries = document.querySelectorAll (query);

    selectedQueries.forEach ( (chkBox) => {
        box.innerHTML += chkBox.title + '<br/>';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML will not support `\n` because it will treated as white space. Use `<br/>` tag for line break.

```
var box = document.createElement( 'div' );
box.id = 'myAlertBox';

document.body.appendChild( box );

box.textContent = text + '<br/>';

var selectedQueries = document.querySelectorAll (query);

selectedQueries.forEach ( (chkBox) => {
    box.textContent += chkBox.title + '<br/>';
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data is being added as text to a textbox. This is the result: `06481-CT TECHNOLOGIST<br/>002561-CT TECHNOLOGIST (OP)<br/>`

Comment: if that is the case you should use `textarea` not `textbox`. `textbox` will not support new line.

Comment: For `textarea` you can use `\n`